# Handle lost visual odometry with IMU sensor fusion

Tags: slam, navigation, ekf, ros-kinetic, rtabmap-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to fuse data from an IMU and a visual odometry node with [robot_localization](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/robot_localization/html/index.html) in order to have a better localization for my robot.
The IMU is a Tinkerforge [IMU Brick 2.0](https://www.tinkerforge.com/en/doc/Hardware/Bricks/IMU_V2_Brick.html); the visual odometry node is the one provided in the package [rtabmap_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros). 
Both nodes work well, and the extended kalman filter does what it's supposed to do.
I am using ROS kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04. 
The only issue that I'm facing is when the visual odometry gets lost: in this case the node publishes a message like that:

```
header:
   seq: 769
    stamp:
       secs: 1522407457
       nsecs: 640873928
    frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "kinect2_base_link"
pose:
    pose:
       position:
          x: 0.0
          y: 0.0
          z: 0.0
      orientation: 
          x: 0.0
          y: 0.0
          z: 0.0
          w: 0.0
    covariance: [9999.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9999.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9999.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9999.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9999.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9999.0]
twist:
    twist:
       linear:
          x: 0.0
          y: 0.0
          z: 0.0
       angular: 
          x: 0.0
          y: 0.0
          z: 0.0
     covariance: [9999.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9999.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9999.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9999.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9999.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9999.0]
```

In this case the kalman filter still continues to work, and this results in the estimante odometry having an erroneous translational velocity.
How can I face with this?
I was thinking about a way to "pause" the kalman filter until the visual odometry returns working but actually I can't figure it out.

Thank you in advance for all your support!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287084/handle-lost-visual-odometry-with-imu-sensor-fusion/) by [nicopal](https://answers.ros.org/users/34398/nicopal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-03-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dronist](https://answers.ros.org/users/55781/dronist/) on 2020-07-29**:
I've tried to fuse the data from the visual odometry with the IMU(all from the realsense D435i)
And I'm getting this drift as shown in the video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-_k5nmxgYUYPFH6EEnVOruqDtIrEcOlu/view?usp=sharing
The second the visual odometry gets lost the odometry starts drift
Even when Im setting publish_null_when_lost to false
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, you can set parameter `publish_null_when_lost` to false of the visual odometry node. Optionally, you can also set `Odom/ResetCountdown` to 1 to automatically reset odom when lost. Make sure `publish_tf` of visual odometry node is false too if you are using [robot_localization](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/robot_localization/html/index.html).

If you are using odometry's velocity, note that I just [committed](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/commit/dc29b741112eb17b458f223e23cdabd339b15208) a fix to avoid publishing null velocity when `publish_null_when_lost` is false. In other words, visual odometry won't publish odometry until a valid velocity can be computed.

EIDT: Note that without rebuilding from source the package, you can also just republish the odometry message from visual odometry only if the values you need are valid.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2018-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nicopal](https://answers.ros.org/users/34398/nicopal/) on 2018-04-03**:
Thank you very much matlabbe! Your help is precious!